# Onclick and $(this) in java/jq function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really simple question. Why doesn't

```
<div class="plus-button" onclick="voteUp(' . $postid . ')" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="like">+ ' . $voterow['totalupvotes'] . '</div>
```

work with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function voteUp(postid){
        var postid = postid;
        $(this).siblings('.minus-button').removeClass('disliked');    
        $(this).toggleClass('liked');

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"php/votesystem.php",
            dataType : 'html',
            data:'act=like&postid='+postid,
            success: function(data){
                $('.plus-button').html(data);
                alert("Liked with id "+postid);
            }
        });
}

</script>
```

The div line works fine. The problem is that $(this) in the java/jq script is not recognized as a specific div class.

I have tried using voteUp(this) and didn't get it to work. Also tried using

```
var postid = $(this).data('postid');
```

but my alert msg then says undefined id instead of whatever id it should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: is this $postid defined by php ? `voteUp(' . $postid . ')`

Comment: you need to use `onclick="voteUp.call(this, ' . $postid . ')"`

Comment: Yes of course. It's defined several times in a php while loop.

Comment: On different objects that is...

Comment: @MohitArora You stitched it together. Thank you.

Comment: You have a very simple issue - the postid needs to be quoted if it is not a number  - also no need to use inline onclick as you can see from my post. I fail to see why you chose to complicate things with .call(this...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of just calling voteUp( #postId) use the call method so voteUp.call(this, #postID);

```
<div class="plus-button" onclick="voteUp.call(this, ' . $postid . ')" data-postid="' . $postid . '" name="like">+ ' . $voterow['totalupvotes'] . '</div>
```

what you basically do here is that you change the context of the function or the "this" variable from the function prototype to the div dom object. more can found in the documentation below :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Complicating a very simple thing here. Still an issue with the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onclick and use jQuery to get the postid

```
$(function() {
  $(".plus-button").on("click",function() {
    var postid = $(this).data("postid");
    // $(this) is now the div clicked
    $(this).siblings('.minus-button').removeClass('disliked');    
    $(this).toggleClass('liked');
    .
    .
```

Comment: Did that before I changed it to onclick. Onclick resolved the issue though.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Use the event handling of jQuery instead of inline onclick and your problem is solved. It is the recommended way and you even save bandwidth by not having the onclick on each div